ReferenceError: dirname is not defined in SvelteKit production build using mpd-api
I'm encountering an issue with a SvelteKit application in production. The app uses the mpd-api module in a server-side function to provide Now-Playing data to the client. While it works fine in development and preview environments, it throws a ReferenceError: dirname is not defined error when built with npm run build and run with node build.
The following is the +server.js file:
import mpd from "mpd-api";

export async function GET({ url }) {
        const station = url.searchParams.get("station");
        const client = await mpd.connect({ path: `/radiosa/socks/${station}` });
        const nowPlaying = await client.api.status.currentsong();
        const status = await client.api.status.get();
        // disconnect to avoid issues with abandoned open connections
        await client.disconnect();
        // Calculate remaining time
        const remainingTime = (Math.max(0, status.time.total - status.time.elapsed) + 4);
        return new Response(JSON.stringify({ nowPlaying, remainingTime }), {
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        });
}

The error seems to originate from the mpd-api module, specifically this function in /lib/api/loadspec.js:
const doLoad = async (docspec = false) => {
  docspec ? debug('loading full spec for documentation') : debug('loading')

  const specFiles = await readSpecFiles(path.join(__dirname, 'spec'))

  for (const file of specFiles) {
    const spec = await parseSpec({ file, docspec })
    for (const key in spec) {
      SPEC[key] = spec[key]
    }
  }

  return SPEC
}

Here is the error message, just in case:
file:///radiosa/sveltekit/build/server/chunks/_server-Dxv5CarM.js:2374
          const specFiles = await readSpecFiles(path.join(__dirname, 'spec'));
                                                          ^

ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined
    at doLoad (file:///radiosa/sveltekit/build/server/chunks/_server-Dxv5CarM.js:2374:52)
    at loadspec.load (file:///radiosa/sveltekit/build/server/chunks/_server-Dxv5CarM.js:2360:21)
    at api.apifyClient (file:///radiosa/sveltekit/build/server/chunks/_server-Dxv5CarM.js:6111:32)
    at Object.connect (file:///radiosa/sveltekit/build/server/chunks/_server-Dxv5CarM.js:6178:14)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5)
    at async GET (file:///radiosa/sveltekit/build/server/chunks/_server-Dxv5CarM.js:6206:21)
    at async render_endpoint (file:///radiosa/sveltekit/build/server/index.js:1610:20)
    at async resolve2 (file:///radiosa/sveltekit/build/server/index.js:4144:22)
    at async respond (file:///radiosa/sveltekit/build/server/index.js:4039:22)
    at async Array.ssr (file:///radiosa/sveltekit/build/handler.js:1272:3)

Node.js v22.9.0

Sveltekit v2.0.0
mpd-api: v1.1.2
I'm looking for a way to allow CJS modules server-side, or a way for the built instance to have the same environment as development or preview instances (npm run dev, npm run preview). Any help or guidance would be appreciated.
I tried the following:

npm run build -- --mode development to change vite build mode.



    const mpd = require("mpd-api");
    
    export { mpd };




    module.exports = {
      connect: async function(options) {
        const mpd = require('mpd-api');
        return mpd.connect(options);
      }
    };

Options 2 and 3 were attempts to resolve mpd-api package using cjs, then import it to the +server.js as an ES module.
